# BackgroundWorker threading issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm getting the infamous "Cross-thread operation not valid" exception when trying to implement a simple BackgroundWorker. I've spent hours reading everything I can find on the subject, including the many related questions on SO, but I'm just not getting it.

I have a simple winform that has a DoWork() method:

1. It takes a delegate representing the work to be done.
2. It creates a `BackgroundWorker` and assigns the delegate to the `DoWork` event.
3. It calls `RunWorkerAsync()`.

The function invoked by `RunWorkerCompleted()` tries to update a label on the form, but throws a cross-thread exception.

```
Public Class MyForm

    Public Sub DoWork(workToDo As DoWorkEventHandler)
        Dim worker As New BackgroundWorker()
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler worker.DoWork, workToDo
        AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        resultLabel.Text = "Done!" ' Exception thrown here
    End Sub

End Class
```

So it looks like `WorkerCompleted` is running on the background thread. Am I close to a working solution, or am I failing to grasp the fundamentals?

### Update: A Mysterious Fix

I discovered a "fix" by dumb luck. We have to look further up the application. This is part of a VSTO Excel Add-In. I was instantiating my form in a ribbon Load event and then calling `Show()` when a button was clicked.  This raised the exception.

```
Private Sub Ribbon1Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mProcessing = New MyForm()
End Sub 

Private Sub Button1Click(sender As System.Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mProcessing.Show()
    mProcessing.DoWork(AddressOf UpdateData)
End Sub
```

Moving `mProcessing = New MyForm()` to the Click handler eliminates the exception.  All is working well. I moved the code back and forth several times and am confident in the problem/solution.

Comment: Works for me.  Please show an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Steven: I stumbled upon a fix.  See my update.

Comment: The generic diagnostic is that System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current is Nothing when the ribbon's Load event fires.  Something you can check with a debugger.  This is very unhealthy and points at a bigger underlying problem, one you should not ignore.

Answer (score 2):

The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is generally run on the same thread as the `BackgroundWorker` itself (UI thread) so I doubt that's the problem here. I suspect your error is occurring during the `DoWork` method and just being thrown once you hit the UI thread. The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) state:

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error and AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled properties before accessing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property. If an exception was raised or if the operation was canceled, accessing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property raises an exception.

On the off chance you *are* hitting a problem with the `RunWorkerCompleted` event not running on the UI thread then you can always invoke the UI update to run on the correct thread using `Invoke` e.g.

```
resultLabel.Invoke(Sub() resultLabel.Text = "Done!")
```

Comment: I was checking for errors; I just pared-down my code when posting.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong off hand, but this can happen. I haven't seen it much, but I have seen it, and had to handle it like this:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() resultLabel.Text = "Done!")
Else
    resultLabel.Text = "Done!"
End If
```